# Десериализация Bson c# и динамическое подключение dll библиотек

Tags: c#, json, dll, рефлексия

Всем доброго времени суток, друзья. 
Есть проект, в котором подключаются dll фигур с помощью рефлексии. При сериализации подключены все библиотеки, однако при десериализации одну из них удалили. Как сделать, чтобы десериализатор пропускал тип элементов, которого более нет и продолжал корректную работу с остальными?

```
using (BsonReader reader = new BsonReader(ms))
{
   var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
      TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
   });
   shapeCollection.Set(serializer.Deserialize<ShapeCollection>(reader));
}
```

При такой записи возникает ошибка:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Error resolving type specified in JSON 'labN1.Rectangle, Rectangle'. Path 'ShapeList[1].$type'."
Внутреннее исключение:
JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'Rectangle'.
```

Рассмотрено на примере удаления библиотеки Rectangle.dll.
Возможно я что-то напутал, так как:

```
try
{
   Assembly a = Assembly.Load("аRectangle");
   Type type = a.GetType("labN1.FactoryMethodes.RectangleFactory");
   object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   MethodInfo rectangleFactory = type.GetMethod("CreateObject");
   object value = rectangleFactory.Invoke(obj, new object[] { new[] { 120, 30, 
   40, 50, (Object)Color.Black, 2 } });
   shapeCollection.ShapeList.Add((Shape)value);
   types.Add(value.ToString());
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Rectangle.dll не подключена.");
}
```

Если допустить ошибку при подключении библиотеки Rectangle.dll ("aRectangle"), а саму библиотеку не удалять, то все будет работать без ошибок, но десериализовывать Rectangle. Которые, впрочем, затем можно удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал через JSON, на выходе получилось 2 метода.
Суть:

  1) Сериализую каждый объект на новую строку.

  2) Читаю строку и   пытаюсь ее десериализовать.

  3) Если десериализация успешна, то заношу в list, иначе обрабатываю исключение 
  и перехожу к пункту 2

```
public void SerializeToJson(String path)
{
  ShapeCollection shapeCollection = ShapeCollection.Instance();
  foreach (Shape shape in shapeCollection.ShapeList)
  {
     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
     {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects};
     File.AppendAllText(@path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shape, settings));
     File.AppendAllText(@path, "\r\n");
  }
}


public void DeserializeFromJson(String path)
{   
  ShapeCollection shapeCollection = ShapeCollection.Instance();
  shapeCollection.ShapeList.Clear();
  shapeCollection = ShapeCollection.Instance(); 
  String line;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@path))
  {
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
       line = sr.ReadLine();
       try
       {
          var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
          {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects};
          var shape = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(line, settings);
          shapeCollection.ShapeList.Add((Shape)shape);
       }
       catch
       {
       }
    }
  }
}
```